# Error `OAuth signature not defined` with Ionic-Angular app

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic-framework, oauth

I have an ionic-angular app `nkvshopapp` with wordpress as backend. Wordpress is locally hosted with oauth1.0 plugin and oauth keys defined.

Until yesterday morning, `nkvshopapp` was working fine and it displayed all of posts and categories from my wordpress website. It stopped working all of a sudden and now it displays error `OAuth signature not defined`. [image: OAuth signature not defined error] I double-checked OAuth keys and they were same as before (i.e. not regenerated anew). App`s index.html and config.ts both are same as before. My app is designed to load an additional Javascript (nkvshopapp.js) so I checked OAuth function within nkvshopapp.js too (in case anyone hacked my PC and made changes to it...getting paranoid, I know :)

Finally, I double-checked in Postman if Oauth keys are being authenticated; and Postman does not display any error or warning. [image: Call validation in Postman]

Am I missing anything? Any suggestions or pointers would be very helpful. 
Pls help.

Here are extracts of index.html, config.ts and nkvshopapp.js.

**./index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>NKVShop</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="nkvshopapp.js"></script>

  </script>-->
```

**./app/www/nkvshopapp.js:**

```
function OAuthSignature() {
}

OAuthSignature.prototype.generate = function (httpMethod, url, parameters, consumerSecret, tokenSecret, options) {
    var signatureBaseString = new SignatureBaseString(httpMethod, url, parameters).generate();
    var encodeSignature = true;
    if (options) {
        encodeSignature = options.encodeSignature;
    }
    return new HmacSha1Signature(signatureBaseString, consumerSecret, tokenSecret).generate(encodeSignature);
    //return new signatureBaseString;
};

// Specification: http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor14
// url: if the scheme is missing, http will be added automatically
function SignatureBaseString(httpMethod, url, parameters) {
    //parameters = new ParametersLoader(parameters).get();
    this._httpMethod = new HttpMethodElement(httpMethod).get();
    this._url = new UrlElement(url).get();
    this._parameters = parameters;
    //this._parameters = new ParametersElement(parameters).get();
    this._rfc3986 = new Rfc3986();
}

SignatureBaseString.prototype = {
    generate : function () {
        // HTTP_METHOD & url & parameters
        return this._rfc3986.encode(this._httpMethod) + '&'
            + this._rfc3986.encode(this._url) + '&'
            + this._rfc3986.encode(this._parameters);
    }
};
```

**./src/providers/service/config.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
declare var oauthSignature: any;
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;    charset=UTF-8');
@Injectable()
export class Config {
url: any = 'http://127.0.1.1:8080/wordpress';
consumerKey: any = 'Hl8XcAPgCqt6';
consumerSecret: any = '3xGMKgiXBP7HoI2i9dkf3HByepZRSmSjYGQNszvXwzfOO0YW';
oneSignalAppId: any = '';
googleProjectId: any = '';
language: any = 'english';
appDir: any = 'ltr';

appRateIosAppId: any = '12345678';
appRateAndroidLink: any = '';
appRateWindowsId: any = '12345678';
shareAppMessage: any = 'download it';
shareAppSubject: any = 'Hi';
shareAppURL: any = '';
shareAppChooserTitle: any = 'select app';
supportEmail: any = 'nkvshopapp@gmail.com';

oauth: any;
signedUrl: any;
randomString: any;
oauth_nonce: any;
oauth_signature_method: any;
encodedSignature: any;
searchParams: any;
customer_id: any;
params: any;
options: any = {};
constructor() {
    this.options.withCredentials = true;
    this.options.headers = headers;
    this.oauth = oauthSignature;
    this.oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    this.searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    this.params = {};
    this.params.oauth_consumer_key = this.consumerKey;
    this.params.oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    this.params.oauth_version = '1.0';
}
setOauthNonce(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install it:

```
npm install oauth-signature
```

And then import it this way?

```
import * as oauth from 'oauth-signature';
```

Hope it helps.